# Allow CORS header causes ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, python, cors, basehttpserver

I'm trying to send a POST request to localhost and was getting an error about CORS not being allowed. I added an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header among other things based on what other people have suggested, but am now getting a different error: "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE". I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm getting wrong!

server side code

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import json
import csv

HOST_NAME = 'localhost' 
PORT_NUMBER = 9000 

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers')

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        # send some json as response
```

client side code

```
axios.post('http://localhost:9000', {
    'cat': 'meow meow meow'
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
```

This is what the console shows:

```
spread.js:25 OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/ net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
(anonymous) @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r.request @ spread.js:25
r.(anonymous function) @ spread.js:25
(anonymous) @ index.js:20
(anonymous) @ (index):232
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
z @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
onSuccess @ (index):221
connected @ link-initialize.js:1
(anonymous) @ link-initialize.js:1
(index):239 Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (spread.js:25)
```

Am I using do_OPTIONS correctly? What about send_response(200) and end_headers()?

Comment: To troubleshoot, try sending an OPTIONS request to `http://localhost:9000/` using curl or Postman or some other tool; e.g., with curl: `curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/`

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks for the suggestion! here's what I get when I do that: 

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: –

I'm not too familiar with curl; what does this mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Could not resolve host* means you gave curl something it thinks is a URL but when curl tries to make a request to that URL, it can’t find a host that matches the hostname in the URL. I guess that means there’s something wrong with the syntax of your curl invocation. It seems like it’s trying to make multiple requests. Anyway, it doesn’t matter, because those response headers indicate you’re getting a response of some kind to at least one request.

Comment: Try adding self.end_headers() to the end of your do_OPTIONS(self) function in your Python code. The error message seems to indicate Chrome thinks the HTTP response it’s getting is malformed—because I guess it’s expecting a newline after the headers. https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers seems to indicate the only thing end_headers() actually does is “Sends a blank line, indicating the end of the HTTP headers in the response”, but I guess without that, an HTTP client doesn’t know that the headers have actually ended.

Comment: hmm when I add end_headers(), I get this in the console: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Although the data I wanted to POST does get sent over to my server (I write it to CSV).

Comment: Your do_POST function doesn’t cause an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be sent back. So to fix it, add `self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` to your do_POST function. The reason the POST succeeds anyway is, the browser doesn’t actually block the POST request from being sent; instead it sends it but blocks your frontend code from accessing the response the server sends back after getting the POST. The reason the browser blocks access to the response is, it doesn’t have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header; so the fix is, add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the response.

Comment: Just for my understanding: what is the purpose of sending the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the do_OPTIONS function in the first place then? I thought the point of do_OPTIONS was to enable CORS for other requests. Or do I have to enable CORS for each function?

Comment: You must enable CORS for each function; that is (in the case of your code), for each method you handle. Every response must include at least the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header; if any response doesn’t include that, then the browser won’t allow your frontend code to access the response. That’s basic and fundamental to CORS; that’s how CORS works. The purpose of adding the header to the OPTIONS to response is just to get the CORS preflight to succeed so that the browser will move on to actually sending the POST request in your code. But the POST response still needs follow the rules too.

Comment: Ahh got it, thank you so much!! :)